# Referencing list elements in R is ambiguous - how to do it right?

Tags: r

Using lists in R seems to be tricky. I was not aware that referencing list elements with identical first part of name is ambiguous:

```
opts = list()
opts$value = NULL
opts$valueDefault = c(1,2,3)

print(opts)                # note: displaying the whole list does not reveal 
                           # the element "value"
$valueDefault
[1] 1 2 3 



print(opts$value)          # with this notation I do not get the correct (intended) 
                           # result
[1] 1 2 3

print(opts[["value"]])     # with this notation I do
NULL
```

Comment: Note that setting a list element to NULL is the same as removing it from the list.  Your list at that point literally only contains a single element called valueDefault.  Try setting value to NA instead to see the difference.

Comment: You should read over `?"$"`

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response: referencing the (not existing) NULL element of course returned NULL - the same as if I e.g. did
    print(opts$another)

Comment: And to summarize briefly - one difference between referencing via `$` and via `[[` is that `$` will do partial matching.  So since your list only contained valueDefault and you said opts$value it realized that you must be referring to valueDefault.  opts[["value"]] doesn't try to do partial matching (by default).

Comment: Might as well turn this into a brief answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that setting a list element to NULL is the same as removing it from the list. Your list at that point literally only contains a single element called valueDefault. Try setting value to NA instead to see the difference.

Reading over `?"$"` will give some more info on this. And to summarize briefly - one difference between referencing via `$` and via `[[` is that `$` will do partial matching. So since your list only contained valueDefault and you said `opts$value` it realized that you must be referring to valueDefault. `opts[["value"]]` doesn't try to do partial matching (by default)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list element to be `NULL`, you have to create a list with `NULL`.

```
opts <- list(value = NULL)

> opts
$value
NULL
```